# Spring LDAP template usage for user authentication per request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ldap, spring-ldap, ldap3

I have a catch 22.

I am implementing a service client whose responsibility is to authenticate a user at an LDAP server. The client accepts a userid and password, determines the userDn, and invoke a request to the LDAP server.

My problem is the way spring ldap template is setup at the moment. The `LdapTemplate` requires a `ContextSource` at bean creationtime. The `ContextSource` is configured at creation time to some value (ldapurl, userdn, password). But I realized that my `ContextSource` will change with each user. Each user opens a connection based on the user's DN. So, my contextsource is different per user and therefor creating a `ContextSource` at beancreation time(container startup) is not the right place. And, there is no way of overriding the `ContextSource` (with the userid/password) through the `LdapTemplate` AFAIK.

So, is it a good idea to create an Ldap `ContextSource` object explicitly in my code by initializing it explicitly with the actual userid and password (and the url of which is a constant over all users) and update my `LdapTemplate` bean by using the setter method of `LdapTemplate`? After my client call I will dispose the `ContextSource` by setting it to `null` (the template outlives the operation because it is a bean living in the spring container. So it could be reused and therefor the previous information on the context must not be available.)

**Question:**
Is there another solution to this problem as described above?

Comment: Is it a good idea to change a singleton bean which is used by multiple threads... What happens if you change the source from 10 threads simultaneously?... So is it a good idea, no it isn't.

Comment: Instead set a `AuthenticationSource` on the `ContextSource`, the default uses a hardcoded instance. You can make it so that it will retrieve the user/password from a `ThreadLocal` or if you are using Spring Security (which I suggest instead of creating your own solution) you can use the `SpringSecurityAUthenticationSource`.

Comment: @M.Deinum  Having read your comment about the template being a singleton makes me realize that this approach could be a wrong choice. That is, the template declared in a spring configuration and being updated with a new contextsource instance by different threads. Indeed if these threads work concurrently they access the same template which has been updated by different threads each with their own version of contextsource! Not the way to go. Another way, the ldaptemplate could be defined/created also within the method which implements the connection to the ldapserver.

Comment: The ldaptemplate will no longer be be a spring bean but it will be created by my code. The same for contextsource.  Besides your suggestion about the AuthenticationSource is there also another solution? (If not using springsecurity)

Comment: Instead of creating all those objects the `AuthenticationSource` is the easiest (apart from using Spring Security).

Comment: Can you point me to an example using the authenticationSource? I ve just checked out this interface but I wonder what is the point of implementing this interface if I can not pass the userid and password from within my method. May be I am missing something...?

Comment: You store them in a `ThreadLocal` inside your method and you have an `AuthenticationSource` which retrieves them from the `ThreadLocal`. That way you have a thread safe implementation. Just make sure you clear the thread local after the request finished.

Comment: Ok. I get it, your suggestion. Unfortunately this is not the direction I can proceed with. My authentication service client is depending on a username-password combination as method arguments. ThreadLocal fits indeed with the AuthenticationSource approach. Apparently it is the only "clean" and safe solution... :-(. I am afraid that I don't have other alternatives, other than your suggestion and my suggestion  I described before. That is, creating myself the template and contextsource in the method which calls the ldapserver. In order to be threadsafe.

Comment: I still don't see the problem... Your authentication client doesn't need to change the signature, only your implementation needs to change... And in the method you just set the values. You don't really want to create an `LdapTemplate` each time you need one, you also need to create the other objects needed all in all quite the overkill for a simple call (and it is quite a heavy operation as well).

Comment: I understand. I will check that out. In a nutshell, userid and password would be put on on a ThreadLocal at the beginning of the request (in the controller) and down the road the serviceclient will offload the userid and password from thread/threadlocal and invoke a call to the ldapserver. The AuthenticationSource is part of ldaptemplate so that userid and password are accessed in threadlocal. This approach would be safe (concurrently) and the same contextsource, that is the AuthenticationSource, would service connections with different userdn / passwords. (Right?)

Comment: Just checked the source code of LdapTemplate and discovered or concluded that there is not much happening with a LdapTemplate at creation/construction time. Actually nothing happening other than an assignment of ContextSource instance. The setters are just ordinary property setters. So no heavy lifting here either. The next call on LdapTemplate would be one of its methods like search(...) or authenticate(...) which does not change the internal state of LdapTemplate itself. So, even though LdapTemplate could be a shared object by different threads concurrently, it is still safe.

Comment: So, creating an instance of LdapTemplate in a method for each request won't demand much cost. Most probably ContextSource would cost more than LdapTemplate. So, I think relocating LdapTemplate from spring configuration to method level and creating a template on request basis is ok and safe..